# How to Deploy a New Version of an Application to Run Side-by-side with an Existing Version?

Tags: android

I need the current version and the previous version of my app to be on the device at the same time.  How can this be done?

Currently the next version just rewrites the previous version.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is not possible to run two application with same package name at same time. But you can do it with different package name.

You can use `productFlavors` with `applicationIdSuffix` to create different package name for same application in different flavors.

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {...}

    // Specifies one flavor dimension.
    flavorDimensions "version"

    productFlavors {
        prod {
            dimension "version"

            applicationIdSuffix ".prod"
            versionNameSuffix "-prod"
        }

        dev {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            versionNameSuffix "-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Above configuration create two flavors named **prod** and **dev** with applicationId suffixed *prod* and *dev* respectively. So, you can run your old version in **prod** mode and new one with **dev** mode. Hope this will help you.

In Android Studio use **View -> Tool Windows -> Build Variants** to change flavor

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can not do this since every application has a unique identifier which is called "package name" (com.example.appname)
But what you can do is to have 2 Emulators and run different per device

Comment: Can I change the package name?